# How to collect statistics about java integration tests

Tags: java, spring, maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

My development environment includes Maven, Failsafe and Spring testing IS (AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests).
I'm looking for a way to collect statistics about the integration tests run.
Information such as Test duration, process memory, etc...
What is the best way to collect such information with the above configuration (and to integrate with the maven flow).

Comment: I would say that probably you can get some of the data from Sonar, but I don't know if sonar has a plugin to report memory / cpu usage.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i recall, the surefire plugin is able to [write reports](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#reportsDirectory) to some directory (which will be used by e.g. jenkins to present results)

Answer (score 0):

There is a maven plugin for [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org). It is highly configurable, maybe solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The failsafe plugin generates a xml file with the tests result. this can be used, for example by a jenkins plugin.